How to erase personal data from a MacBook Pro that is locked via MDM
I am dealing with a company MacBook Pro model A2918, M3 chip, made in 2023. The company terminated me, and I am trying to remove my personal data from it before returning it. However, the company locked me out of the machine and is refusing to let me back into it. They claimed they would wipe the machine when they receive it, but I don't entirely trust them and want to remove things on my end first.
Currently when I open the laptop, I see "This Mac is Locked. The System PIN is required to use this Mac." They have another admin user account on Mac OS and have Kandji MDM software set up on the machine. Not sure if this screen is from Kandji or something else.

I do have Find My set up on the device under my user account, and I do see the device when I log into iCloud on another machine, so could try to remote erase the device using Find My, but I'm not sure if that would be effective given the lock screen I am seeing.
Personal data that I want to remove includes:

Emails saved locally using Apple Mail
Calendar events saved locally using Apple Calendar
Passwords synced locally using 1Password 6
Files synced locally in Google Drive for desktop
Logins to various services (including Google) in Firefox, Chrome, and Mac OS (for Apple Mail and Calendar)
iCloud account
Contacts
iMessage conversations

I can remote log out from some of these things but am really looking for a single "erase" option at the OS level if possible. What are my options?

Welcome to Ask Different. While locking out a terminated employee from company resources is standard policy and that's why they won't let you log in (even to delete your data), you may still ask that an IT employee sign you out of iCloud and delete your account in your presence when returning the computer. If you don't think that's feasible, if you enabled Remote Login, you could try logging in using SSH to get command-line access and remove your account folder. I'd be surprised if you were able to erase the device using Find My, but is definetely worth a try.

@jaume it’s a fully remote company, so returning the computer in person is not an option. I have to mail it back.

I see, another option would be to start up your work Mac from an external disk or a flash drive (for example, from an OS installer), that would let you erase the drive. If you have access to another Mac (ideally of the same type) you can create the OS installer (see https://support.apple.com/101578), plug it into the work Mac (you need to connect the disk to a compatible port except the DFU port, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/111336#connect), select Disk Utility and erase the drive. This may not work because of MDM, and will not work if the IT department disabled external startup disks.

@jaume I followed those instructions, and when I tried to start up the work Mac with the startup options window (holding the power button), it just loaded “This Mac is locked” again. Anything else to try?

Wait, I think the "erase" from Find My worked - after I saw that "This Mac is locked" screen, the machine rebooted and then went into recovery mode and showed me an erase option (but I think it had been erased already).

remote erase the device using Find My seemed to work - after restarting the Mac, I saw “This Mac is locked” again, but then the machine restarted itself again and seemed to erase itself.
